# firebase silently fails at pushing object

Tags: angular, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

When I try to push an object to firebase it silently fails without alerting me of any errors and my code stops at that point. It seems to fail to complete. Oddly enough it runs fine on the browser but on ios simulator or device it fails to complete. I'm so confused this should be so simple.

```
firebase.database().ref(`payments/${this.currentCustomer.uid}/${id}`)
  .push({reservation: payment.reservation})
```

I tried console logging error by adding a callback but it doesn't log anything

```
currentReservation={  
    time: null,
    type: '',
    day: 'Monday',
    date: null,
    month: null,
    year:'2019',    
    location: {},
    note:''
} 
   firebase.database().ref(`payments/${this.currentCustomer.uid}/${id}`)
      .push({reservation: payment.reservation})
```

The currentReservation gets values from the user. After this, I try to push and the object should be pushed to firebase but it's not.
This works on the browser but not on ios device or simulator.

Comment: 1. Check if you have any Database Rules for update the item
2. Any login needed to update the item
3. Check if any filter applied to error message

Comment: @hugomac This piece of code worked fine before but recently it just fails with no changes made to it. I checked your suggestions but no change

Comment: Is the device able to go online? read data is okay maybe it is due to cache in firebase persistent data. Also, please check the plist if block the http connections

Comment: @hugomac Yes i have pushed another object and it works. I don't understand why this object fails though. I console log the reservation object and there's nothing abnormal

Comment: `ref(`payments/${this.currentCustomer.uid}/${id}`)` is a list or not ? try to use `set` or `update` if it is not a list. What you get if you log `{reservation: payment.reservation}`

Comment: try to change `let data = {reservation: payment.reservation}`  and then try  `ref.push(data)`

Comment: If you could able to push another object, it should be the problem of that object

Comment: ``` {"reservation":{"time":"10:00AM","date":20,"month":2,"year":"2019","location":{"city":"Austin","country":"USA","houseNum":"2d","state":"Tx","street":"blah","zip":"blah"},"note":""}} ``` it returns fine.

Comment: I'm confused as why it works on browser but not on ios device or xcode simulator.